# Can ".filter" check that target has multiple attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

I have a checkbox filter set up and I am using .filter to filter some divs.

Here's my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var checkboxes = $('div.filter-groups').find('input:checkbox'),
general = $('.general');

function filterCheckboxes(){
    var checked = checkboxes.filter(':checked');

    general.hide();
    $.each(checked, function(){
    var rel = $(this).data('filter');

        general.filter('.' + rel).show();
    });
}

checkboxes.on('click', filterCheckboxes);
});
```

Here is the web page: 
http://www.bluehavenhomes.com/floor-plans?hs_preview=1SQuQUzB-2347415373

here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanSumner90/nh8vr1kp/1/

I need `.filter` to check that the div has all of the checked boxes attributes before displaying. Any Suggestions?

secondly why is it that when I check and then uncheck a/the box(es) that all of the divs no longer appear? can this be fixed?

Comment: A quick read here http://api.jquery.com/filter/ learned me that `filter` supports a function or callback.

Comment: Just fyi, your jsfiddle doesn't match the code you posted in your question.

Comment: Yes but I know that already. What kind of function would you use to compare the class items of a div to the data- of multiple checked check boxes before assigning either hide or show?

Comment: rogMaHall Sorry I fixed the link.

Comment: what does `div has all of the checked boxes attributes before displaying` mean? Not even clear what expected behavior is or what `attributes` you are talking about

Comment: Seriously? ok so each checkbox has a data-filter attribute. regardless of how many checked boxes are checked I need only the divs containing the classes that correspond to the values of the checked checkboxes data-filter attributes to show.

Answer (score 0):

You had two problems:

- You hide all divs but never show it.
- You hide at each :checked input, so only one filter is taken into account.

From your jsFiddle:

`$(document).ready(function () {
            $('div.filter-groups').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
                $('.general').hide();
                var selectors = [];
                var filters = $('div.filter-groups').find('input:checked');
                filters.each(function () {
                    selectors.push('div.general.' + $(this).attr('rel'));
                });
                if (filters.length == 0)
                    $('.general').show();
                else {
                    var selector = selectors.join(", ");
                    $(selector).show();
                }
            });
        });`

I didnt fully tested this code.
Hope it helps.